# selecting the next m rows after row number n in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

In a mysql table with "R rows" I want to select the next "m rows" after "nth row" in such a way that if n+m>R it returns R-n rows from the end of table and m+n-R rows from the beginning of the table.

e.g in this table:

```
id firstname
1   john
2   robert
3   bob
4   adam
5   david
```

I want to get the next 4 rows after row number 3 (bob), in this fashion:

```
4 adam
5 david
1 john
2 robert
```

I have searched a lot and found that the following query just returns the last 2 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 4 OFFSET 3;
```

I know that I can implement this specific query using php and bunch of conditional statements but I am curious to know whether it has been implemented in mysql or not?

Comment: No, that has not been implemented in MySQL (directly), because that is just too specific and uncommon a request.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `union all` in a subquery.  This allows you to "duplicate" the table, with a newly calculated id at the end of the table:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*, id as newid from table t) union all
      (select t.*, id + cnt as newid
       from table t cross join
            (select count(*) as cnt from table) cnt
      )
     ) t
order by newid
limit 4 offset 3;
```

For small tables, this should be fine.  For larger tables, you probably don't want to do this because the MySQL materializes the subquery -- adding overhead to the processing of the query.